# Working with multiple return datasets from different functions python pandas

Tags: python, function, csv, pandas

I am working with 3 data sets, I wrote 3 different functions, 1 per data set to do some data cleaning and manipulation. In the end I want to combine all 3 cleaned data sets in another function.

my logic:

```
import pandas as pd
def function1():
    read in data as df
    df[(df.column1 != "")&(df.column2 != 'MRN')&(df.column3 != "C") ]
    return data1.to_csv() 

def function2():
    read in data as df
    df[(df.column1 != "A")&(df.column2 != 'M')&(df.column3 != " ") ]
    return data2.to_csv() 

def function3():
    read in data as df
    df[(df.column1 != "B")&(df.column2 != 'N')&(df.column3 != " ") ]
    return data3.to_csv() 

def combinedatasets():
    merge (data1, data2, data3)
    return combineddata.to_csv()
```

Now i'm outputting data1,data2 and data3 as a new file in the directory. Is there anyway to store them temporarily inside the script so these 3 files would not be outputted, and only the combineddate.csv will be outputted? 
**How do I call these temporary datasets, data1,data2,data3 from my first 3 functions inside my combineddatasets function to combine them?**

so something like:

```
import pandas as pd
def function1():
    read in data as df
    df[(df.column1 != "")&(df.column2 != 'MRN')&(df.column3 != "C") ]
    return temporary data1 without outputting it

def function2():
    read in data as df
    df[(df.column1 != "A")&(df.column2 != 'M')&(df.column3 != " ") ]
    return temporary data2 without outputting it

def function3():
    read in data as df
    df[(df.column1 != "B")&(df.column2 != 'N')&(df.column3 != " ") ]
    return temporary data3 without outputting it

def combinedatasets():
    calling temporary data1,2,3 and 
    merge (data1, data2, data3)
    return pd.to_csv('combineddata.csv') #output as a csv file
```

so only the 'combineddata.csv' will be outputted to the folder.

Comment: What do you mean by *combine*? Appending them, merging them, or other? Also can you not show psuedo code as it very hard to see your issue since `read_csv` is not a method of any other object except as a general `pandas` method. Did you mean `to_csv`?

Comment: yeah I am using pandas, let me edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply assign an object to function call since function returns a dataframe:

```
def myfunction():
    data = pd.read_csv('Input.csv')
    # process dataframe...
    return data

def combinedatasets():
    df = myfunction()
```

Or simultaneous assignment:

```
def combinedatasets():
    data1, data2, data3 = function1(), function2(), function3()
```

However, avoid multiple dataframes of similar structure in your environment and save dataframes to a list which you can then merge or append together:

```
def combinedatasets():
    dfList = [function1(), function2(), function3()]

    # MERGE/COLUMN BIND
    combinedf = pd.concat(dfList, axis=1, join_axes=[dfList[0].index])
    combinedf.to_csv('CombinedWideData.csv')

    # APPEND/ROW BIND
    combinedf = pd.concat(dfList)
    combinedf.to_csv('CombinedLongData.csv')
```